# Массив и разбивание его на переменные

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой и никак не могу решить.

Есть таблица базы данных, в ней 2 поля: ИМЯ и ЦЕНА (в ней, допустим, два товара).
Мне нужно сначала вывести оба имени и потом снова занести их в таблицу, но уже в другую, которая также содержит поля: ИМЯ и ДАТА.

Проблема заключается в том, что не могу добавить во вторую таблицу имена товаров из первой.
Скажем, массив с именами у меня - `$row["name"]` и вот не знаю, что нужно сделать, чтобы во вторую таблицу добавилось ДВЕ СТРОКИ, в каждой по имени.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table_name2 (name, data) SELECT name, NOW() from table_name WHERE критерий_отбора
```

Можно как-то так например

Answer (score 0):

выполни запрос

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (name) Value (".name1."),(".name2.")";
```